# Microsoft Contracts: Assembly load resulted in metadata import warning

Tags: .net, code-contracts, design-by-contract, contracts, microsoft-contracts

I'm trying to learn my way around the [Microsoft Code Contracts](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/) libraries, and I have the following simple function:

```
internal static Engine CreateBuildEngine(Microsoft.Build.Framework.ILogger logger)
{
    Contract.Requires( logger != null );

    var engine = new Engine { DefaultToolsVersion = "3.5" };
    engine.RegisterLogger(logger);
    return engine;
}
```

When attempting to compile this, the contracts static compiler throws up the following warning message:

```
warning : contracts: Assembly load resulted in metadata import 'Could not resolve member reference: Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.Engine::set_DefaultToolsVersion.'
```

and then promptly gives up (and doesn't attempt to do any further contract processing).
If I remove the code which sets `DefaultToolsVersion` then the contract verifier works correctly, however this is rather pointless as it will cause the code to be incorrect.

I can't find any mention of this on google... Is there some way that I can fix this, or is it just a bug in the contracts library? (admittedly it's in pre-release status)

Thanks

Comment: Are you using the latest CC? I just pasted your code into an empty project and it compiles fine.

Comment: Oh dear, just realised I had my StackOverflow filtered to "unanswered" questions, have been answering old questions for a while now... :P